# Find shortest collection of roads connecting 4 towns at 4 corners of rectangle with lengths 1 and 'a' for sides of rectangle

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, optimization, word-problem

This problem is from MIT's Single Variable Calculus course.
a) Show that the shortest collection of roads joining four towns at four
corners of a unit square is given by roads that meet at 120◦ angles. Use the
variable x as indicated on the picture. This is not the picture included with the problem but works just as well:

[image]

For part a), the perimeter is a unit square. For the length, I used$$L = 4\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + x^2} + (1 - 2x)$$ Finding the derivative of $L$ and setting it equal to zero, I found that $$x = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$$ so $$L = 1 + \sqrt{3}$$

As for the angle, $$\tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2x}$$ so $$\theta = 2\arctan(\sqrt{3}) = 120^{\circ}$$

b) Find the shortest collection of roads in the shape indicated for towns
at the four corners of a rectangle. Write down the formula for the length of the
roads as a function of $a$. Hint: Sometimes the answer is that the roads meet at
$120^\circ$ angles, but only for certain values of $a$.

What I'm really struggling with is writing the length $L$ as a function of $a$. Referring to linked photo, $b = 1$ and $a$ is the unknown length of the rectangle.

One attempt was rewriting $L$ as above but replacing $1$ with $a$:
$$L = 4\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + x^2} + (a - 2x)$$
I took the derivative, treating $a$ as a constant and again have $$x = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$$
Plugging this into the original equation, I have $$L = \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} + a$$
I'm not sure if this is the right approach. I've tried solving for $x$ in terms of $a$ but I'm getting that $$x = \frac{a}{4}$$ which would only be true if $a =1$.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Hi, I've inlined your image and made some MathJax tweaks, but in so doing, noticed that you have a curious function $\arctan^{-1}$.  That would seem to be just $\tan$.  Probably the $-1$ shouldn't be there?

Comment: You're right, Brian. I meant just arctan. Thank you for pointing that out. Also, thank for including the image and cleaning up the formulas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work appears to show that, as a function of $a$, where fixed $b=1$, $$L = a+\sqrt3$$is the shortest collection of roads linking the four towns. Since setting the derivative equal to $0$ gives the same minimum value of $x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt3}$ for all lengths of the rectangle, the four corner roads do not change in length or angle with increasing $a$. Only the middle road that joins the four increases. And since $$tan\frac{\theta}{2} =\frac{.5}{x}=\sqrt3$$ is also fixed, it seems the roads meet at $120$ degree angles for all values of $a$.